# Retain UserName in Twitter iOS5 iPhone

Tags: iphone, twitter, ios5

I want to hit add a button that allows the user to sign into their twitter account in iOS 5, but I want their twitter handle to populate into a UITextField. I have code to make sure their iPhone is running iOS 5 and their account is enabled. How do I retain their handle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    //get Twitter username and store it    
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if(granted) {
            NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

            ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];
            ;
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:twitterAccount.username forKey:@"twitterHandle"];
        }

    //get the username later...
    [textField setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"twitterHandle"]];
```

Comment: Your valueForKey should be twitterHandle.

Comment: There's a couple issues with that code, but it works great once you change a few things (ex. standDefaults = standardUserDefaults)

Answer (score 0):

You can get their handle out of the ACAccount object and save it in a default or elsewhere.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011019-CH1-DontLinkElementID_5